# Apache vhost not redirecting

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect

I have a subdomain sub.example.org with an A record showing to my server IP.

On the server I have /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.example.org.conf with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.org
    ServerAlias www.sub.example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/sub 
    DirectoryIndex index.html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.example.org.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.example.orgaccess.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

After a2ensite and reloading the conf, I try to open the site in my browser and get greeted with the example.org welcome page. The URL still says sub.example.org, tho.

Also an additional comprehension question: Do I actually need to set a subdomain at my domain reseller or can Apache handle this alone?

Comment: This is not how `vhosts` work. Your `DocumentRoot` should be `/var/www/sub.example.org` just among `/var/www/example.org`

Comment: Could you provide some logs (e.g. ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log and ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.example.orgaccess.log)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was, because I have a catch-all ServerAlias for the main domain, which triggers before my subdomain reacts.